# Save cnet / download.com downloads to disk

Tags: download

I downloaded a program from cnet. It wasn't downloaded directly but with a download tool from cnet, (which tried to install other programs or toolbars too).

I would like to save the downloaded program and not only the cnet downloader to disk. Where is the installer stored? It doesn't seem to be in '%TEMP%'

Comment: There usually is a small text link for direct download under those tacky green download buttons that download a "downloader". I always prefer direct download to the crappy downloaders.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found it: the downloader saves the original download-file in your download-folder!

Comment: Wow. Shocker. Just to let people know. This is the download folder on both OS X and Windows. Actually, same with Linux. Don't worry about it dropping it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Temp`.

I found my program in a folder in the above location called `dlm8219.tmp`.

I am using Windows 7 and I have the `show hidden folders` option enabled.